# Keep getting "There is already another Tungsten installation script running"

Tags: mysql, mongodb, tungsten-replicator

I'm trying to install tungsten replicator 3.0.0-524 GA from MySQL to MongoDB but when I'm running the `cookbook/validate_cluster` the error:

> There is already another Tungsten installation script running
>   (InstallationScriptCheck)

Keep showing up

The configuration I'm using for the cluster are:

```
./tools/tpm configure mysql2mongodb \
--enable-heterogenous-master=true \
--topology=master-slave \
--master=mysql \
--replication-user=boahub_boahub \
--replication-password=*****\
--slaves=tracking-mongo \
--home-directory=/opt/mysql \
--svc-extractor-filters=replicate \
--property=replicator.filter.replicate.do=boahub_boahub.urls,boahub_boahub.media_campaigns \
--start-and-report

./tools/tpm configure mysql2mongodb \
--hosts=tracking-mongo \
--datasource-type=mongodb \
--replication-port=27017

./tools/tpm -v install --install-directory=/opt/tungsten
```

I've configured both "mysql" and "tracking-mongo" hosts under /etc/hosts file

So far I've tried to 
 1. Reboot the system
 2. Clear my /opt/tungsten installation directory
 3. Delete the deploy.cfg

The verbose output of the `tools/tpm -v install` shows the SSH between the two machines succeeded and the command for checking other tungsten script is

```
ps ax 2>/dev/null | grep configure.rb | grep -v firewall | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'
```

When I execute this command it comes up with nothing.

What can I do? Is there and way to ignore this check?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove any check using `--skip-validation-check` option(argument required). You can use this option multiple time without problem.

The option takes as argument the name of the check which can be found in the error message.

In your case you can add the following option to your command:

```
--skip-validation-check InstallationScriptCheck
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this may help you get through.

Have you tried install your master and slave separately? Do a

```
./tools/tpm install
```

after configuring & installing master, clear the configuration with

```
./tools/tpm configure defaults --reset
```

Then apply your slave settings and do the other tpm install.

A few weeks ago I had run into some similar (maybe, I can't recall as clear) trouble. The phrase "another script" in your post has brought back some memory of that for me, hope it works.

Good Luck!